# At what point should I add a comma after a relative clause

Tags: relative-clauses

I read an article that said, the general rule of thumb Is "Defining relative clause" do not need a comma before the relative clause. An example is this:

> The students who work hard are more likely to do well in their exams.

and I also have this statement.

> I met my friends yesterday. The friend, who had curly hair, was very intelligent.

why does the second sentence have a comma before the relative pronoun who, when it is a defining relative clause?

Shouldn't the statement read:

> I met my friends yesterday. The friend who had curly hair was very intelligent.

Comment: Your first version (the one with the commas) is nonsensical straight away because it refers to singular ***the*** friend, whereas the preceding sentence refers to meeting plural ***my friends***.

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* a defining relative clause.  You know this because of the commas.

It is a non-defining relative clause.  It just tells us an extra piece of information about the friend.

The full paragraph looks wrong, since we don't know which friend you mean.  So you *should* use a defining clause:

> I met my friends yesterday. The friend who had curly hair was very intelligent.

Or you could choose not to determine the friend:

> I met my friends yesterday. One of my friends, who had curly hair, was very intelligent.

Those are weird and artificial examples. The first does define the friend by their hair type, and then describes them.  The second doesn't determine which friend, but gives two pieces of unrelated information about this person.  (The tense in the second question is also strange, "... is very intelligent" - because they haven't become stupid overnight.

Now, that is a lot of work for a pair of commas to do.  And so don't expect every natural sentence to "follow the rules". In natural English the distinction between "defining" and "non-defining" clauses is not as clear as the textbook says.

This example isn't natural and has only been created to show the difference.